# export/import contact in skype for business

Tags: skype-for-business

Joined a company using skype for business. Surprised to find there is no folder hierarchy, import/export contact list. (maybe business is so easy to be ripped off these days). Haven't found an existing tool to interact with skype client to export/import contact. Some tool (http://support.express-desk.com/support/Skype-for-Business-Online-Contact-Manager) need office365 admin permission which I don't have. 
Is there open source (ex: lib skpy or @github) to share global team skype hierarchy among teammates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first you need to understand that Skype for Business online (hosted by Microsoft in the cloud) isn´t the same as Skype for Business on Premises (selfhosted inside your organization). Most features are identically however some are a little bit different (mostly not seen by the user).

So both solutions use a centralized share to host contacts which only an Administrator can manage. On an on premises environment an Skype for Business Administrator might add an contact to the global Adressbook. However this often results in a kind of garbage as more and more such contacts where created here and they where never cleaned up. So most companies to not perform that and relay on the users to keep there own contacts locally.

The link you mentioned is by the way nothing else as an 3rd party GUI for the so called "Unified Contact Store" (more infos [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/skype-for-business-online-instant-messaging-presence-and-contacts.aspx#Unified%20Contact%20Store)).

The normal way by the way to import / export contacts is via Outlook. The MS Exchange server is normally connected to the Skype for Business environment and therefore will sync the contacts (if configured correctly as explained [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4015948/deprecation-of-skype-for-business-contacts-folder-in-outlook-and-outlo) or [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3193240/outlook-skype-for-business-contacts-folder-doesn-t-sync-with-skype-for)). So in theory you could export your contacts and send that over to your team. They all can import them and you can then see those in Skype for Business.

*P.S. Please keep noted that the contact list is limited to something around 200 entries (see [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/skype-for-business-online-instant-messaging-presence-and-contacts.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)). And allows an Administrator to manage that via GUI. However a 3rd party software isn´t really something which is supported by Microsoft, so most companies might not have a look into that to avoid to break something.*